# fancybox 2 как растянуть изображение на всю страницу?

Tags: fancybox

Всем привет!

Изначально изображения в галерее различного размера и разной ориентации

Хотелось бы чтобы они автоматом разворачивались на всю страницу либо по ширине, либо по высоте в зависимости от ориентации изображения.
сейчас делаю так:

```js
   $('.fancybox').fancybox({
                minHeight: $(window).height(),
                maxHeight: $(window).height(),
                fitToView: true
            })
```

Но если изображение имеет, например, соотношение 3:1 - появляется горизонтальная прокрутка, как можно избежать этого?

И еще один баг при таком подходе - при изменении размеров окна браузера, не меняется minHeight и maxHeight.

Пытался использовать

```js
$(window).resize(function () {
                $.fancybox.update();
            })
```

не помогает:(

Answer (score 2):

```
minHeight: 900,
maxHeight: 900,
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?